# java.sql.SQLException: Smart-large-object error springboot informix connection

Tags: spring-boot, informix

i trying to use informix database(9.4) with spring boot application  ( informix jdbc  version 4.10.8.1 ) , but  i have  this error "java.sql.SQLException: Smart-large-object error" & "Smart Large Objects: No sbspace number specified"
i don't use any blob object in my code .

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.10.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Smart-large-object error.
>       at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:474) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:443) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:394) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3191) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3472) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2379) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2304) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFastPath(IfxSqli.java:5199) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeFastPath(IfxSqli.java:5131) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSmartBlob.IfxLoCreate(IfxSmartBlob.java:370) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxLob.(IfxLob.java:127) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxCblob.(IfxCblob.java:64) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.createClob(IfxSqliConnect.java:7188) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>       ... 44 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Smart Large Objects: No sbspace number specified.
>           at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildException(IfxErrMsg.java:474) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>           at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:443) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>           at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:394) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>           at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3477) ~[jdbc-4.10.8.1.jar:4.10.8.1]
>           ... 52 common frames omitted

Comment: It isn't complaining about a BLOB but rather a CLOB. So apparently you are using large texts in your code or something else that gets mapped to CLOB.

Comment: @M.Deinum now  i try  to create a  new simple table 'CREATE TABLE informix.todo_items
(
   id           serial         NOT NULL,
   name         varchar(50)    NOT NULL,
   description  varchar(200),
   todo_date    date,
   status       varchar(20)    NOT NULL
)'  remains the same problem  ,but when i use data source explorer it work perfectly

Comment: 4.10.JC8 JDBC is old, but IDS 9.4 is something else. It's from 2000.
The stack trace you put above clearly shows that the driver is trying to create a CLOB. What's the complete stack? Can't see why you would get that stack with a simple table like "todo_items".

Comment: Does your server (IDS 9.40 — I can't emphasize too much that the server is very archaic and should have been upgraded a decade or more ago) have any smart blob spaces (sbspaces) configured?  Your comment suggests that you originally tried to create a different table schema.  I wonder if you ran the modified SQL statements, or accidentally ran the original ones again?  Did you include a CLOB or BLOB type?  Did you specify which sbspace it should be stored in — see the (11.50) [PUT clause](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0107.htm#ids_sqs_0107).

Comment: IDS 9.40 was released by IBM after the acquisition of Informix in 2001.  I have records saying that in 2004, 9.40 was the current edition, in 2005, 10.00 was current.  I believe 9.40 was released after 2001 and not later than 2004.  I believe 9.30 was the first IBM release, from late 2001 or early 2002.  It doesn't make a lot of difference; IDS 9.40 should not still be in use.  It has been out of support for about a decade.